# Correcting tick marks

Tags: r

How to I change the y-axis tick marks to only increase by 0.1 starting at 3.5?

Here is my code

```
NCM_Viz <- ggplot(NCM_Summary, aes(date, daily_max,  color = 'red3')) + 
geom_point() +              
labs(x= "Date", y = "Peak Velocity", title = "NCM Squat Jump - 20kg Peak Velocity")
```

[image]

Comment: It would be easier to help if you share a small reproducible example. Add `dput(NCM_Summary)` to your post. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Answer (score 0):

You can set the scale using `scale_y_continuous`.

```
library(dplyr)
NCM_Summary <- tibble(
    Date = as.Date(c("2021-03-15", "2021-03-21")), 
    `Peak Velocity` = c(3.77, 3.65))

ggplot(NCM_Summary, 
    aes(x = Date, y = `Peak Velocity`)) + 
    geom_point(color = 'red3') + 
    scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(from = 3.5, to = 3.8, by = 0.1), limits = c(3.5, 3.8)) +
    labs(title = "NCM Squat Jump - 20kg Peak Velocity")
```

[image: Two red points with scale set]